# How to Display Progress Dialog for Android Robotium Test:

Tags: android, testing, progressdialog, robotium

**Main Class:**

```
public class ProgressIndicator {
    static ProgressIndicator instance;
    Context context;
    public static ProgressIndicator getInstance() {

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ProgressIndicator();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private ProgressIndicator() {

    }
    IndicatorThread sd;
    public void showIndicator(Activity activity, String title, String message, boolean flag) {
        sd = new IndicatorThread(activity, title, message, flag);
        sd.start();
    }

    public void dismissIndicator(Activity activity) throws InterruptedException{
        sd.dismiss();
        // sd.join();
    }

    private static class IndicatorThread extends Thread {

        private static final Message listener = null;
        private static String mTitle;
        private static String mText;
        private Activity mActivity;
        private boolean mflag;
        private ProgressDialog mDialog;

        protected boolean dismiss;

        IndicatorThread(Activity activity, String title, String text, boolean flag) {
            super();
            IndicatorThread.mText = text;
            IndicatorThread.mTitle = title;
            this.mActivity = activity;
            this.mflag = flag;
            if (mDialog == null) {
                mDialog = new ProgressDialog(mActivity);
                mDialog.setTitle(mTitle);
                mDialog.setMessage(mText);              
                mDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                mDialog.setCancelable(true);
                mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                if(mflag == true){
                    mDialog.setButton("Cancel", listener);
                    mDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                            mDialog.dismiss();
                            interrupt();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            mDialog.show();
            mDialog.getWindow().setLayout(160, 350);
            mDialog.getWindow().setGravity(0);
        }

        public void dismiss() {
            dismiss = true;
            mDialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("notifying..."+dismiss);
            synchronized (this) {
                notifyAll();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Running..."+dismiss);

            while (!dismiss) {
                System.out.println("waiting..."+!dismiss);

                synchronized (this) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                        ie.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Quitting...");
        }
    }
}
```

**Call from AppController class:**

```
private ProgressIndicator progressInstance = null;
public void showWaitingAnimation(Activity parent) {
    progressInstance.showIndicator(AppController.getInstance().currentActivity, "" , "", false);
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
public class ProgressIndicatorTest extends
    ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyTestActivity> {

    private Solo solo;

    private ProgressIndicator progressIndicatorInstance;

    public ProgressIndicatorTest() {
        super("com.test.activity",
                MyTestActivity.class);
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        AppController.getInstance().startApp(getActivity());
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
        progressIndicatorInstance = ProgressIndicator.getInstance();
    }

    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        try {
            solo.finalize();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        getActivity().finish();
        super.tearDown();
    }

    public void testGetInstance() {
        try {
            ProgressIndicator instance = ProgressIndicator.getInstance();
            assertNotNull(instance);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail("Creation of ExceptionDetails get instance failed!");
        }
    }

    public void testShowIndicator()  {
        Log.d("testCase Name:-", "testShowIndicator");

        ProgressIndicator progressInstance = ProgressIndicator.getInstance() ;
        progressInstance.showIndicator(AppController.getInstance().getCurrentActivity(), "" , "", false);
        //AppController.getInstance().showWaitingAnimation(AppController.getInstance().getCurrentActivity());
            solo.waitForDialogToClose(8000);
        try {
            progressInstance.dismissIndicator(AppController.getInstance().getCurrentActivity());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void testDismissIndicator() {
        Log.d("testCase Name:-", "testDismissIndicator");
        ProgressIndicator progressInstance = ProgressIndicator.getInstance() ;
        progressInstance.showIndicator(AppController.getInstance().getCurrentActivity(), "" , "", false);
        solo.waitForDialogToClose(2000);
        try {
            progressInstance.dismissIndicator(AppController.getInstance().getCurrentActivity());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //AppController.getInstance().showAppTerminationDialog("", AppController.getInstance().getCurrentActivity());
    }
}
```

While running the project the dialog is visible & working properly. But while running the test case only a black screen is visible, no dialog is getting displayed (after using solo.waitForDialogToClose(8000); problem is there). No error or exception is getting thrown and the test cases are getting passed in Android Junit test. If anyone has any idea how to display this progress dialog in case of robotium test, Please share.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I can successfully display progress dialogs.
I simply used

```
boolean showProgressBar = false;
showProgressBar = solo.waitForText("Verifying and Saving Credentials...", 1, 3000);
```

I hope it should also work for you.. :)

Comment: As mentioned I've used...............................                             ProgressIndicator progressInstance = ProgressIndicator.getInstance() ;
    progressInstance.showIndicator(AppController.getInstance().getCurrentActivity(), "" , "", false);
    //AppController.getInstance().showWaitingAnimation(AppController.getInstance().getCurrentActivity());
        solo.waitForDialogToClose(8000);                        but it's not working....but in application its working

Comment: And If I check with the solo.waitForText it returns that it's getting the text, but screen used to be black only.